# How can I transfer my PSP saves to the PPSSPP emulator?

Tags: emulation, psp, ppsspp

I kept all my PSP's save data and imported it to my PS Vita, but long term my PC may get more PSP action than the Vita. Thanks to Content Manager, I DO have copies of all of my PSP games in a digital format on my PC, currently in a backup folder. Seems like there must be some way to get PPSSPP to use these since I already have the files on PC.

Is it as simple as copying those PSP folders to some directory for PPSSPP? If so, where? If not, is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is as simple as copying the files over from the memory stick/backup folder. The target directory for your saves inside the PPSSPP folder is `PPSSPP\memstick\PSP\SAVEDATA`. An example of a correctly placed PSP save would be `PPSSPP\memstick\PSP\SAVEDATA\ULUS10036001`.

Comment: Yep, works. Well that was the easiest transfer from official hardware to emulation ever